# How to validate a filename in JAVA to resolve CWE ID 73(External Control of File Name or Path) using ESAPI?

Tags: java, owasp, esapi, veracode

I am facing this security flaw in my project at multiple places. I don't have any white-list to do a check at every occurrence of this flaw. I want to use ESAPI call to perform a basic blacklist check on the file name. I have read that we can use SafeFile object of ESAPI but cannot figure out how and where.

Below are a few options I came up with, Please let me know which one will work out?

`ESAPI.validator().getValidInput()` or 
 `ESAPI.validator().getValidFileName()`

Answer (score 1):

Blacklists are a no-win scenario.  This can only protect you against *known* threats.  Any code scanning tool you use here will continue to report the vulnerability... because a blacklist **is** a vulnerability.  See this note from [OWASP:](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation)

> This strategy, also known as "negative" or "blacklist" validation is a
>   weak alternative to positive validation. Essentially, if you don't
>   expect to see characters such as %3f or JavaScript or similar, reject
>   strings containing them. This is a dangerous strategy, because the set
>   of possible bad data is potentially infinite. Adopting this strategy
>   means that you will have to maintain the list of "known bad"
>   characters and patterns forever, and you will by definition have
>   incomplete protection.

Also, character encoding and OS makes this a problem too.  Let's say we accept an upload of a *.docx file.  Here's the different corner-cases to consider, and this would be *for every application in your portfolio.*

1. Is the accepting application running on a linux platform or an NT platform?  (File separators are `\` in Windows and `/` in linux.)
   a.  spaces are also treated differently in file/directory paths across systems.
2. Does the application already account for URL-encoding?
3. Is the file being sent stored in a database or on the system itself?
4. Is the file you're receiving executable or not?  For example, if I rename `netcat.exe` to `foo.docx` does your application actually check to see if the file being uploaded contains the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files) for an exe file?
5. I can go on.  But I won't.  I could write an encyclopedia.

If this is across multiple applications against your company's portfolio it is your ethical duty to state this clearly, and then your company needs to come up with an app/by/app whitelist.

As far as ESAPI is concerned, you would use `Validator.getValidInput()` with a regex that was an OR of all the files you wanted to reject, ie. in `validation.properties` you'd do something like: `Validator.blackListsAreABadIdea=regex1|regex2|regex3|regex4`

Note that the parsing penalty for blacklists is higher too... every input string will have to be run against EVERY regex in your blacklist, which as OWASP points out, can be infinite.

So again, the correct solution is to have every application team in your portfolio construct a whitelist for their application.  If this is *really* impossible (and I doubt that) then you need to make sure that you've stated the risks cited here clearly to management and you refuse to proceed with the blacklist approach until you have written documentation that the company chooses to accept the risk.  This will protect you from legal liability when the blacklist fails and you're taken to court.

[EDIT]

The method you're looking for was called `HTTPUtilites.safeFileUpload()` [listed here as acceptance criteria](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Secure_Coding_Guideline) but this was most likely never implemented due to the difficulties I posted above.  Blacklists are *extremely* custom to the application.  The best you'll get is a method `HTTPUtilities.getFileUploads()` which uses a list defined in `ESAPI.properties` under the key `HttpUtilities.ApprovedUploadExtensions`

However, the default version needs to be customized as I doubt you want your users uploading `.class` files and `dll` to your system.

Also note:  This solution is a `whitelist` and NOT a `blacklist.`

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet works to get past the issue CWE ID 73, if the directory path is static and just the filename is externally controlled :

```
//'DIRECTORY_PATH' is the directory of the file
//'filename' variable holds the name of the file
//'myFile' variable holds reference to the file object

File dir = new File(DIRECTORY_PATH);
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(filename);
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
File myFile = null ;
if(files.length == 1 )
   myFile = files[0];
```